# textfield inner text spacing

Tags: html, css

i want to give space from left to text inside textfield  something like inner padding but not change the size of my textfield .

here is my css

```
    form input{
       width: 263;
       height:43;
       border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
       line-height: 1.5em;
       padding-right:15;
    }




<form  action="contact_page.php" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="n" placeholder="Name" size="34"/>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="e" placeholder="Email" size="34" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <textarea cols="54" rows="7" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Send It Now..." />
        </form>
```

Comment: Its `padding-right:15px` and use `box-sizing: border-box` too so `padding` won't affect `width` of your input field.

Comment: add padding-left :10px; change width:253px;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-sizing:border-box` this will not make add padding value in with width it will adjust `padding` value width `width`.

And you need to add `px` in your `css`attribute value

```
form input{
   width: 263px;
   height:43px;
   border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   padding-right:15px;
   padding-left:15px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the CSS property `box-sizing` that can be used: [MDN box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
// example of box-sizing
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

// how to modify your example
form input{
   border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 43px;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   padding-right: 15px;
   width: 263px;
}
```

jsBin example: [http://jsbin.com/yizuru/](http://jsbin.com/yizuru/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-indent`:

```css
input[type=text][name=n] {
  text-indent: 5px
}
```

```html
With text indent:
<input type="text" name="n" placeholder="Name" value="Alex" />
<br/>Without text indent:
<input type="text" name="e" placeholder="Email" value="abc@xyz.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

Css code:

```
form input{
   width: 263px;
   height:43px;
   border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   padding-right:15px;
   padding-left:15px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Html Code:

```
<form  action="contact_page.php" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="n" placeholder="Name" size="34"/>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br />
            <input type="text" name="e" placeholder="Email" size="34" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <textarea cols="54" rows="7" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Send It Now..." />
        </form>
```

[DEMO PAGE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/0nbt0sLb/)